# Calling multiple objects from one vector of names within an R function

Tags: r, arguments

I have several objects in my R environments that are named with the same prefix (for instance, 'test.'). Each object is the result of a model fitting. I want to automatize the comparison among models, by first, defining the vector of the names of such objects:

```
list_obj<-ls(pattern="test.")
```

And, then, put the list of objects within the R function that summarise the models and identify the best model among all 'test.' objects.

```
result<-summarize(list_obj)
```

However, this approach is not correct and does not work.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: How do you identify the best model? You can get all models in a list by `model_list <- mget(ls(pattern="test\\."))`

Comment: Your suggestion did not work. The function 'summarize' has the required method to compare models (AIC). And I would use the function in the following way: res<-summarize(test.1, test.2, test.3)

Answer (score 0):

Get the models in a list and use `do.call`

```
res <- do.call(summarize, mget(ls(pattern="test\\.")))
```